# How to remove the header values in spring integration using header-filter?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I'm using a `header-enricher` in spring integration to add some info to message header.

```
<int:header-enricher input-channel="inboundReqOutboundChannel"
        output-channel="validRequestChannel">
        <int:header name="original-payload" ref="messageCreator"
            method="reqHeaderEnricher"></int:header>
</int:header-enricher>
```

After the header is enriched, the request message is passed on as below.

```
header-enricher --> channel --> jmsOutboundgateway
```

Then the response message flow is as below.

```
    jms-message-driven-adapter --> service-activator --> channel --> 
header-filter --> channel --> from here to jmsOutboundgateway's reply destination
```

The header-filter in response message flow is as below

```
<int:header-filter input-channel="headerFilterChannel"
        header-names="original-payload" output-channel="responseOutChannel" />
```

But the response message is still having the `original-payload` header even after passing the `header-filter`.

Any additional configuration need to be done for `header-filter` to work properly?

Please point me the correct approach.

Many thanks for suggestions!

**Debug Logs:**

After the message passes the header filter in responseFlow:

> header-filter --> intermediateRespOutChannel --> jmsOutboundAdapter --> to
>   jmsOutBoundGateway

The `original-payload` header is removed when the message passes the `intermediateRespOutChannel` after the `header-filter`.

```
2015-07-25 17:07:14,306 DEBUG [org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel] preSend on channel 'headerFilterChannel', message: GenericMessage [payload=javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement@e7e6f9, headers={transaction_id=WSG91075596120150725170705797, sequenceNumber=1, sequenceSize=1, WsGwCorrelationID=5c57f681-9b08-4c6f-8bdb-c400dd5299a2, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1437824232246, uri=http://localhost:8082/OnlineSOAPBinding/soapui/OnlineReqSOAPBinding, ffp=AB, sendingsys=AB, jms_redelivered=false, OutboundRetroCorrelationKey=520a0ea3-465c-4b92-aa4c-ed32703aae5e, jms_replyTo=queue://PAI_RES_INTER_OUTQ, ws_soapAction=processRequest, original-payload=SomeValueFromRequest, id=d8af82e0-3555-0df9-7c8a-ce082c2e7ec7, jms_messageId=ID:01HW370406-53356-1437823659837-1:2948:1:1:1, receivingsys=SZ, timestamp=1437824233993}]
2015-07-25 17:07:14,306 DEBUG [org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler] org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler#2 received message: GenericMessage [payload=javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement@e7e6f9, headers={transaction_id=WSG91075596120150725170705797, sequenceNumber=1, sequenceSize=1, WsGwCorrelationID=5c57f681-9b08-4c6f-8bdb-c400dd5299a2, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1437824232246, uri=http://localhost:8082/OnlineSOAPBinding/soapui/OnlineReqSOAPBinding, ffp=AB, sendingsys=AB, jms_redelivered=false, OutboundRetroCorrelationKey=520a0ea3-465c-4b92-aa4c-ed32703aae5e, jms_replyTo=queue://PAI_RES_INTER_OUTQ, ws_soapAction=processRequest, original-payload=SomeValueFromRequest, id=d8af82e0-3555-0df9-7c8a-ce082c2e7ec7, jms_messageId=ID:01HW370406-53356-1437823659837-1:2948:1:1:1, receivingsys=SZ, timestamp=1437824233993}]
2015-07-25 17:07:14,306 DEBUG [org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel] preSend on channel 'intermeddiateResponseOut', message: GenericMessage [payload=javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement@e7e6f9, headers={transaction_id=WSG91075596120150725170705797, sequenceNumber=1, sequenceSize=1, WsGwCorrelationID=5c57f681-9b08-4c6f-8bdb-c400dd5299a2, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1437824232246, uri=http://localhost:8082/OnlineSOAPBinding/soapui/OnlineReqSOAPBinding, ffp=AB, sendingsys=AB, jms_redelivered=false, OutboundRetroCorrelationKey=520a0ea3-465c-4b92-aa4c-ed32703aae5e, jms_replyTo=queue://PAI_RES_INTER_OUTQ, ws_soapAction=processRequest, id=af627505-55ca-854e-d2e8-1687fa5aca34, jms_messageId=ID:01HW370406-53356-1437823659837-1:2948:1:1:1, receivingsys=SZ, timestamp=1437824234306}]
2015-07-25 17:07:14,306 DEBUG [org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsSendingMessageHandler] org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsSendingMessageHandler#1 received message: GenericMessage [payload=javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement@e7e6f9, headers={transaction_id=WSG91075596120150725170705797, sequenceNumber=1, sequenceSize=1, WsGwCorrelationID=5c57f681-9b08-4c6f-8bdb-c400dd5299a2, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1437824232246, uri=http://localhost:8082/OnlineSOAPBinding/soapui/OnlineReqSOAPBinding, ffp=AB, sendingsys=AB, jms_redelivered=false, OutboundRetroCorrelationKey=520a0ea3-465c-4b92-aa4c-ed32703aae5e, jms_replyTo=queue://PAI_RES_INTER_OUTQ, ws_soapAction=processRequest, id=af627505-55ca-854e-d2e8-1687fa5aca34, jms_messageId=ID:01HW370406-53356-1437823659837-1:2948:1:1:1, receivingsys=SZ, timestamp=1437824234306}]
2015-07-25 17:07:14,309 DEBUG [org.springframework.integration.jms.DynamicJmsTemplate] Executing callback on JMS Session: ActiveMQSession {id=ID:01HW370406-59320-1437824218347-1:5:1,started=true}
```

In downstream flow after jmsOutboundgateway, the debug log is as below

> jmsOutboundGateway --> outboundResAggregatorChannel --> Aggregator --> channel-->

In the `outboundResAggregatorChannel`, the `original-payload` header is again added

```
2015-07-25 17:07:14,561 DEBUG [org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel] preSend on channel 'outboundResAggregatorChannel', message: GenericMessage [payload=javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement@9f7158, headers={transaction_id=WSG91075596120150725170705797, sequenceNumber=1, sequenceSize=1, WsGwCorrelationID=5c57f681-9b08-4c6f-8bdb-c400dd5299a2, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1437824234313, uri=http://localhost:8082/OnlineSOAPBinding/soapui/OnlineReqSOAPBinding, ffp=AB, sendingsys=AB, jms_redelivered=false, OutboundRetroCorrelationKey=520a0ea3-465c-4b92-aa4c-ed32703aae5e, jms_replyTo=queue://PAI_RES_INTER_OUTQ, ws_soapAction=processRequest, correlationId=3d09b492-c4d8-f314-b18d-85dd740ae944, original-payload=SomeValueFromRequest, id=d13a807a-8b89-92d2-5b08-5b767f86774a, jms_messageId=ID:01HW370406-59320-1437824218347-1:5:1:1:1, receivingsys=SZ, timestamp=1437824234561}]
2015-07-25 17:07:14,561 DEBUG [org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AggregatingMessageHandler] org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AggregatingMessageHandler#0 received message: GenericMessage [payload=javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement@9f7158, headers={transaction_id=WSG91075596120150725170705797, sequenceNumber=1, sequenceSize=1, WsGwCorrelationID=5c57f681-9b08-4c6f-8bdb-c400dd5299a2, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1437824234313, uri=http://localhost:8082/OnlineSOAPBinding/soapui/OnlineReqSOAPBinding, ffp=AB, sendingsys=AB, jms_redelivered=false, OutboundRetroCorrelationKey=520a0ea3-465c-4b92-aa4c-ed32703aae5e, jms_replyTo=queue://PAI_RES_INTER_OUTQ, ws_soapAction=processRequest, correlationId=3d09b492-c4d8-f314-b18d-85dd740ae944, original-payload=SomeValueFromRequest, id=d13a807a-8b89-92d2-5b08-5b767f86774a, jms_messageId=ID:01HW370406-59320-1437824218347-1:5:1:1:1, receivingsys=SZ, timestamp=1437824234561}]
```

Comment: Can you post a DEBUG log showing the message flow through the filter? Don't put it in a comment, it won't render well; edit your question instead.

Comment: @Gary edited the question with the debug logs when the message passes through the filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it doesn't work that way. Just because it is `Gateway`. 
So, `jmsOutboundgateway` does know nothing about the flow on the other side and it really isn't interested in. 
There is need just to have a `reply` from there, wrap it to the message and send to the `reply-channel`.

And the main word here is `wrap`. Having the `original-payload` header on the `requestMessage` any gateway implementation transfer them not only to that downstream flow (if protocol supports that, of course), but also to the `replyMessage` - `AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler`:

```
@Override
protected final void handleMessageInternal(Message<?> message) {
    Object result;
....
    result = handleRequestMessage(message);
....
    sendOutputs(result, message);
}

....
if (this.shouldCopyRequestHeaders()) {
    builder.copyHeadersIfAbsent(requestHeaders);
}
```

And so on.

So, for your case you should move (or copy?) your `<int:header-filter>` to the downstream flow on the `reply-channel`.

Comment: Yes Artem..Thanks for pointing this. In the downstream flow after `jmsOutboundGateway`, the headers are copied again even if it is previously removed by the `header-filter` in responseFlow.


Is there a way to configure the `jmsOutboundGateway` not to copy the headers again to the reply message in downstream flow?

Comment: You can do that only extending `JmsOutboundGateway` and implement its `shouldCopyRequestHeaders()` as returning `false`. But that is bad, because you may loose all important headers. Otherwise no: you can do that only with the `<header-filter>` and as we confirmed just after the `jmsOutboundGateway` in the main flow.

Comment: So the `jmsOutBoundGateway` will get only the payload, not the headers from the message received in reply destination and then it will `copy/not-copy` the headers which is available from the requestFlow based on `shouldCopyRequestHeaders()` return value.
i.e it will not use the headers which are modified`(either enriched/filtered)` somewhere in the response flow. 
If that is the case, i will opt for using the header-filter after the jmsOutboundGateway's reply channel.

Comment: still my understanding or my doubt is that why can't it just use the modified headers itself rather than copying it from request flow? fine! i will explore on this more to understand it properly.